# Bulk initialisation and protocols in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, swift-protocols

I have those protocols

```
protocol BaseProtocol: CustomStringConvertible {
   var aVar: Int? {get set}
}

protocol ProtocolA: BaseProtocol {
    init(number: Int)
}

protocol ProtocolB: BaseProtocol {
    init(number: Int, string: String)
}
```

And I have classes:

- `ClassAOne`, `ClassATwo`, `ClassAThree` conform to `ProtocolA`
- `ClassBOne`, `ClassBTwo`, `ClassBThree` conform to `ProtocolB`

So what I want is to write a bulk initialization. Here is an example of what I want:

```
let arrayOfClasses: [Any] = [ClassAOne.self, ClassATwo.self, ClassBThree.self, ClassAThree]

let number = 10
let text = "test"

let initializedObjects = arrayOfClasses.map { classType in
    // This code isn't compilable
    // If class type is a class which conform to ProtocolA - use simple init
    if let protocolA = classType as? ProtocolA {
        return ProtocolA.init(number: number)
    } 
    // If class type is a class which conform to ProtocolB - use longer init
    if let protocolB = classType as? ProtocolB {
        return ProtocolB.init(number: number, string: text)
    }
}
```

Is it possible at all? 
Basically I have array of Class.self as input and I want to have array of initialized objects as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but the result is pretty ugly IMO. `initializedObjects` would have to be `[Any]`, which is a horrible type to work with (and `Any?` might creep in, which is even worse). I'd really recommend just splitting up the classes by type unless that would cause a major headache. That said, it is possible and a useful exploration of how types work Swift.

```
let initializedObjects = arrayOfClasses.flatMap { classType -> Any? in
    switch classType {
    case let protocolA as ProtocolA.Type:
        return protocolA.init(number: number)

    case let protocolB as ProtocolB.Type:
        return protocolB.init(number: number, string: text)

    default:
        return nil // Or you could make this return `Any` and fatalError here.
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I can split it unfortunately. Basically I need to initialize array of `BaseProtocol` objects based on passed to me array of types. The array of types can have mixed order of types of `ProtocolA` and `ProtocolB`. And result array should have same order of initialized objects.

Comment: thans a lot. Actually I jast tested and you don't need to use `Any?` as result type for a flatMap. You can use `BaseProtocol` for that. In that case type of `initializedObjects` will be `[BaseProtocol]`

Comment: Ah, yeah, forgot about `BaseProtocol`. Yeah; that's a good thing.